# phonegap, unable to go back after opening inAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I am developing a phonegap(latest version) application for android and needed to open urls in inAppBrowser. i am able to open urls , but most of the times i am unable to go back to app after hitting back button, the app just freezes. This is the relevant code.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    var ref = window.open('http://google.com','_blank','location=no');
    setTimeout(function(){
        ref.close();
      },2000);
 }
```

But i am able to go back to app, if `target='_system'`